# Linq to XML ( Get specific values under one node)

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

**i have a xml like following one.**

```
  <testing>
  <node01 name="node01Name">
    <node02s>
      <node02 name="1">
        <CustomProperties>
          <CustomProperty Name="ASCII File Name" Value="index.txt" FilterID="0" />
          <CustomProperty Name="ASCII Folder" Value="\\abc\cdf\aaaa" FilterID="0" />
          <CustomProperty Name="Delimiter" Value="CommaQuote" FilterID="0" />
          <CustomProperty Name="Duplicate Handling" Value="Replace if Dup" FilterID="0" />
          <CustomProperty Name="EMAILATTDOC" Value="1" FilterID="0" />
          <CustomProperty Name="EMAILATTINDEX" Value="0" FilterID="0" />
          <CustomProperty Name="EMAILOUTBODY" FilterID="0" />
          <CustomProperty Name="EMAILOUTCC" FilterID="0" />
        </CustomProperties>
      </node02>
      <node02 name="2">
        <CustomProperties>
          <CustomProperty Name="ASCII File Name" Value="index.txt" FilterID="0" />
          <CustomProperty Name="ASCII Folder" Value="\\abc\cdf\aaaa" FilterID="0" />
          <CustomProperty Name="Delimiter" Value="CommaQuote" FilterID="0" />
          <CustomProperty Name="Duplicate Handling" Value="Replace if Dup" FilterID="0" />
          <CustomProperty Name="EMAILATTDOC" Value="1" FilterID="0" />
          <CustomProperty Name="EMAILATTINDEX" Value="0" FilterID="0" />
          <CustomProperty Name="EMAILOUTBODY" FilterID="0" />
          <CustomProperty Name="EMAILOUTCC" FilterID="0" />
        </CustomProperties>
      </node02>
    </node02s>    
  </node01>  
</testing>
```

**I need to get each CustomProperty under each node02. this is my code.**

```
XDocument configparentXML = XDocument.Load("admin.xml");
string node = "node02";

var batchClasses = from batchClasse in configparentXML.Descendants(node)
                   select new ReadingXmlWithLinq
                   {
                       BatchClassName = batchClasse.Attribute("Name") != null ? batchClasse.Attribute("Name").Value : "",
                   };

foreach (var lv0 in batchClasses)
{
    node = "CustomProperty";
    var CustomProperties = from CustomProperty in configparentXML.Descendants(node)                                       
                           select new ReadingXmlWithLinq
                           {
                               CustomPropertyName = documentClasse.Attribute("Name") != null ? documentClasse.Attribute("Name").Value : ""
                           };
}
```

**But in hear its return all CustomPropery Values. How can i get CustomerPropery for a node02 ?**

Thank you very much.

Comment: i accept ur comment. Some answers i have accepted by voting.But I dint confirm it by licking the correct mark.Sorry about that. And thax for the comment. it will never happen again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd approach this with XPath:

```
var xmlString = @"<testing>...</testing>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
var path = "/testing/node01/node02s/node02/CustomProperties/CustomProperty";
var nodeIterator = nav.Select(path);
var nodes =
    nodeIterator
        .Cast<XPathNavigator>()
        .Select(n=>XElement.Parse(n.OuterXml));
```

**EDIT**

To get all nodes under (say) `<node02 name="2">` you could alter the path as follows:

```
var path=
   "/testing/node01/node02s/node02[@name=2]/CustomProperties/CustomProperty";
```

Here's a [page of XPath examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) so you can see what's possible.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. But still i cannot get CustomProperies separately. i need to get what are the CustomProperties under Node02 name 1 and what are the CustomProperties under Node02 name 2 separately.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear to me how you want the data, there's just not enough information here to work with.

Instead, here's an example of how you could select all `node02` elements and grab their names and the names of their `CustomProperty`'s.  This selects *ALL* `node02`'s and *ALL* their `CustomProperty`'s just as your code does.  You don't actually filter anything nor did you specify *which* nodes or properties you wanted.  It's confusing what you really want.  So instead, here's an example showing how you can do what it appears you want to do:

```
XDocument doc = ...;
var batchClasses = doc.Descendants("node02")
    .Select(n => new
    {
        BatchClassName = (string)n.Attribute("name") ?? "",
        CustomPropertyNames = n.Descendants("CustomProperty")
            .Select(cp => (string)cp.Attribute("Name") ?? "")
            .ToList(),
        // Here's an example to select "EMAIL" custom property names
        EmailPropertyNames = n.Descendants("CustomProperty")
            .Select(cp => (string)cp.Attribute("Name") ?? "") // select the names...
            .Where(s => s.StartsWith("EMAIL"))                // that start with "EMAIL"
            .ToList(),                
    });
```